# rspec isn't finding examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I have an almost-new Rails 3.1.0 application, and rspec can't find my examples.

```
duncan@duncan-notebook:~/myapp$ bundle exec rspec
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00004 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

My spec directory looks like this:

```
spec/
|-- controllers
|   `-- welcome_controller_spec.rb
|-- factories
|   `-- users.rb
|-- helpers
|   `-- welcome_helper_spec.rb
|-- models
|   `-- user_spec.rb
|-- spec_helper.rb
`-- views
    `-- welcome
        `-- index.html.haml_spec.rb
```

And there are definitely examples in there.  E.g. `welcome_controller_spec.rb` contains the following:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'    
describe WelcomeController do    
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

I'm running the following versions of rspec & related Gems:

- rspec (2.6.0)
- rspec-core (2.6.4)
- rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
- rspec-rails (2.6.1)
- rubyzip (0.9.4)

Could someone please tell me how to convince rspec to find my examples?  I suspect I'm missing something very simple here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm getting the same results with bundle exec rspec, maybe it was deprecated. Try this instead:

```
 rspec spec
```

Comment: Both `rspec spec` and `bundle exec rspec spec` work nicely.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

@calebB is correct for <= 2.6, but the 2.7 release won't require you to include the directory (it will default to `spec`).